# Limiting visibility of a command in a plugin using visibleWhen in plugin.xml

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin which its command will be displayed only at certain packages which are under a specific package foo.com.network.svc . I found visibleWhen keyword. But I could not use it very well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after a series of trial and error efforts, I managed to limit visibility of the plugin which adds a command on right click at package explorer. Limit is to show command only in a package fragment under specific path. Below is some part of my plugin.xml that affects visibility.

```
<visibleWhen>
```

`<iterate>enter 
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
<test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.path"

value="/foo/com/bar/svc/*"/>
<not>
<test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.path"
value="/foo/com/bar/svc/*/*"/>
</not>
</adapt>
</iterate>
</visibleWhen>`